# Grid view in mvc6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How to add grid view in MVC-6?

I would like to use webgrid something for listing the details. Is it possible to use System.Web.Helpers as namespace. But I am not getting it supporting

Answer (score 2):

This project could fit your requirements, a simple grid control for ASPNET MVC (using Razor): [MVC6.Grid.Web](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [NetCoreControls](https://github.com/ByteNuts/NetCoreControls).

Built specifically for .NET MVC Core.
The Grid Control is server side, uses AJAX, and supports, paging, filter and events.

Check the documentation and demo website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shield UI for ASP.NET Core [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc/) and integrate it with the free [Shield UI Lite](https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite) via Bower, or the commercial Shield UI suite.

Their Grid widget is awesome!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use the jqGrid(or may be some other java scripts grid). From the MVC controller return the ActionResult as JSON object

```
public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        object userListData = null;
        try
        {
            List<UserListViewModel> users = 'your code to get the user list'
            userListData = new
            {
                page = 1,
                records = users.Count,
                rows = users
            };
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(userListData),
            ContentType = "application/json",
        };
    }
```

and call this on page load/jQuery document Ready some thing like this.

```
 $("#userTable").jqGrid({
    url: '../User/UserList,
    mtype: 'GET',
    datatype: "json",
    autowidth: true,
    colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', key: true, hidden: true, fixed: false, shrinkToFit: false, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'FirstName', fixed: false, shrinkToFit: false, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'LastName', fixed: false, shrinkToFit: false, align: 'left' }
    ],
```

for more information about jqGrid, please see  demo at http://jqgrid.com/

Comment: This answer isn't for MVC but javascript. Another issue is that when objects (json) are returned just use an API controller not MVC.

Comment: i upvoted this answer. not sure why it was downvoted twice. ive been searching for a free grid, and while MVC6 grid by NonFactors might be a good option it does not allow editing. i also could not find a reference to webgrid, so im guessing it was not imported into .mvc6. after hours of searching, jqgrid does seem like the best option. this is a good answer because it addresses what was needed, a grid for mvc6, since webgrid does not seem to be an option. this answer could be better by explaining that, and if webgrid was available, this answer could state this as a viable option and why